# SocialAuth Integration in Android

Tags: android

I have integrated socialauth integration in my android application.

But the problem is when I am giving my facebook app id and secret, It is not able to get information from graph.facebook.com.

When I give other facebook app ID (for ex: SocialAuth.in) It is working fine. What could be the problem?

My Logcat as follows:

```
02-14 11:02:34.258: W/System.err(1358): org.brickred.socialauth.exception.SocialAuthException: Error while getting profile from https://graph.facebook.com/me
02-14 11:02:34.258: W/System.err(1358):     at org.brickred.socialauth.provider.FacebookImpl.authFacebookLogin(FacebookImpl.java:205)
02-14 11:02:34.268: W/System.err(1358):     at org.brickred.socialauth.provider.FacebookImpl.doVerifyResponse(FacebookImpl.java:192)
02-14 11:02:34.268: W/System.err(1358):     at org.brickred.socialauth.provider.FacebookImpl.verifyResponse(FacebookImpl.java:178)
02-14 11:02:34.268: W/System.err(1358):     at org.brickred.socialauth.SocialAuthManager.connect(SocialAuthManager.java:184)
02-14 11:02:34.268: W/System.err(1358):     at org.brickred.socialauth.android.SocialAuthDialog$SocialAuthWebViewClient$1.run(SocialAuthDialog.java:246)
02-14 11:02:34.268: W/System.err(1358):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
02-14 11:02:34.278: W/System.err(1358): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=CAAD2WcZBnsZBQBAJ3hOeUWx1JnBY0XpAyOadslebo8H4OM5bZAhysrYYEHU2WynddlR9bQx02I52FHUJGMMd1MA88PUOOD2NBYi2P4qQL7mVxtp9QZCkTFvDvgyZB8ELwWs7xIsCCgrJZCy5cx6ZAwRwpHOzaU5umoKIk3HQrZA5vq80wOYBQvTol72a4k7YtSwZD
02-14 11:02:34.278: W/System.err(1358):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:186)
02-14 11:02:34.278: W/System.err(1358):     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:271)
02-14 11:02:34.288: W/System.err(1358):     at org.brickred.socialauth.util.Response.getResponseBodyAsString(Response.java:103)
02-14 11:02:34.288: W/System.err(1358):     at org.brickred.socialauth.provider.FacebookImpl.authFacebookLogin(FacebookImpl.java:203)
02-14 11:02:34.288: W/System.err(1358):     ... 5 more
02-14 11:02:34.288: D/SocialAuthError(1358): org.brickred.socialauth.exception.SocialAuthException: Error while getting profile from https://graph.facebook.com/me
02-14 11:02:34.288: D/Custom-UI(1358): Error
02-14 11:02:34.288: W/System.err(1358): org.brickred.socialauth.android.SocialAuthError: Unknown Error
02-14 11:02:34.298: W/System.err(1358):     at org.brickred.socialauth.android.SocialAuthDialog$SocialAuthWebViewClient$1.run(SocialAuthDialog.java:262)
02-14 11:02:34.298: W/System.err(1358):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: where u put ur `facebook app id and secret` in java code ?

Comment: in oath_consumer.properties file

Comment: its in`asset` folder right if so `double check` on facebook developer dash board that `ur app is correctly configured`

Comment: I have entered all the fields. How to check whether the app is configured or not?

Comment: hi , please download new sdk. now socialauth android uses native flow. check facebook guide on wiki for use.

Comment: did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem. You have to put your own

```
#facebook
graph.facebook.com.consumer_key = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
graph.facebook.com.consumer_secret = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

from your app on `auth_consumer.propertie`s file from assets

first is FACEBOOK_APP_ID and second is FACEBOOK_API_SECRET